# Django pre_save is not triggered

Tags: python, django, signals

I'm creating an instance of a model (Container), and it seems like the pre_save function is not triggered.

This is the class in the 'signals':

```
class ContainerCreatedMixin(object):
  @staticmethod
  @receiver(pre_save, sender=Container)
  def container_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      # create container folder if not created yet
      if instance.folder_created_at is None:
          is_folder_created = ContainerCreatedMixin().create_folder(instance)

          if is_folder_created:
              instance.folder_created_at = now()

  def create_virtual_folder(self, container):
     try:
        ......
```

Comment: Have you imported that file anywhere so that the signal is registered?

Comment: That's what I was missing! you can write it as answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [receiver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) decorator on a class method doesn't really make sense.

Put your decorated method out of class and it should be registered if the file is imported. Also, there is no need of creating Mixings for the following.

Comment: The specific issue was that I missed the import. Thanks.